# Integrating by parts, where did I go wrong?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Suppose u satisfies $$\left(\partial_{t}^{2}-\partial_{x}^{2}\right) u(x, t)=0,(x, t) \in \mathbb{R} \times(0, \infty)$$

$ $
I'm trying to show:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u(x, t)\left(\partial_{t}^{2}-\partial_{x}^{2}\right) \phi(x, t) \mathrm{d} t \mathrm{~d} x=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, 0) h(x)-g(x) \partial_{t} \phi(x, 0) \mathrm{d} x$$

Where $u(x, 0)=g(x), \partial_{t} u(x, 0)=h(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$

I have:
Multiply the wave equation by $\phi$ and integrate over $\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)$
$$
\begin{gathered}
\left.\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, t) u_{t}(x, t)\right|_{0} ^{\infty}-\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u_{t}(x, t) \phi_{t}-u_{x x}(x, t) \phi(x, t) d t d x \\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, t) h(x) d x-\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u_{t}(x, t) \phi_{t}-u_{x x}(x, t) \phi(x, t) d t d x \\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, 0) h(x)-\phi_{t}(x, 0) g(x) d x+\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u(x, t) \phi_{t t}-u_{x x}(x, t) \phi(x, t) d t d x \\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, 0) h(x)-\phi_{t}(x, 0) g(x) d x+\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u(x, t) \phi_{t t}-u(x, t) \phi_{x x}(x, t) d t d x-\int_{0}^{\infty}( \phi u_{x}-\phi_{x}u)|_\mathbb{R}dt
\end{gathered}
$$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are you possibly supposed to use that u satisfies a PDE?

Comment: Yes, u satisfies $\left(\partial_{t}^{2}-\partial_{x}^{2}\right) u(x, t)=0,(x, t) \in \mathbb{R} \times(0, \infty)$

Comment: How did you get the first line of the equation from the given assumptions? Also, how did you get the second line of the equation without $u_t(x,\infty)$ given?

Comment: This is because u goes to 0 as t goes to $\infty$ (you can prove this using Kircchoff's formula)

Comment: @IH Can you please help me on where I went wrong? The first line is found by multiplying $\phi$ to the equation that u satisfies and then integrating

Comment: The second time you use IBP in $t$ you should put the second $t$ derivative on $u$ instead of back onto $\phi$.

Comment: @Silver54 Right, the point of my question is that you are never using that u satisfies a PDE in your argument. You need to use this at some point. As others have noted, your arguments are missing some steps. I would suggest to write it out more carefully in the question.

Comment: @Jeff I've clarified that in the first step. Apologies that it wasn't clear.

Comment: @Silver54 You've made a few sign mistakes such as in first equality you keep the $t=0$ boundary term which should have a minus and in second equality the sign of $u_xx$ term shouldn't change. Just keep track of those, and evaluate your last integral which has $x$ boundary terms using some properties of $\phi$ (which I believe you need but haven't stated)

Comment: I end up with $=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, 0) h(x)-\phi_{t}(x, 0) g(x) d x+\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u(x, t) \phi_{t t}-u(x, t) \phi_{x x}(x, t) d t d x = 0$ but I'm not sure why it isn't $=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, 0) h(x)-\phi_{t}(x, 0) g(x) d x-\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u(x, t) \phi_{t t}-u(x, t) \phi_{x x}(x, t) d t d x=0$

Comment: The first term is incorrect in your comment above, it should be $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \color{blue}{+} \phi_{t}(x,0)g(x) \color{red}{-} \phi(x,0)h(x) dx$$ IBP gives $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \phi u_{tt} dt dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} [\lim_{t \to \infty} \phi u_{t} \color{red}{-} \phi(x,0) u_{t}(x,0)] dx \color{brown}{-} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \phi_{t} u_{t} dt dx$$ and another application gives $$\color{brown}{-} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi_{t}u_{t} dt dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}[\color{brown}{-}\lim_{t \to \infty}\phi_{t}u \color{blue}{+}\phi_{t}(x,0)u(x,0)]dx + \dots$$

Comment: What are you doing?

Comment: In the PDE at the top of the question, do $\partial_x^2$ and $\partial_t^2$ refer to $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$ respectively?

Answer (score 3):

So if you are trying to show
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u(x, t)\left(\partial_{t}^{2}-\partial_{x}^{2}\right) \phi(x, t) \mathrm{d} t \mathrm{~d} x=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, 0) h(x)-g(x) \partial_{t} \phi(x, 0) \mathrm{d} x$$

why do not simply start with the LHS?

$$\begin{align}&\int_\mathbb{R} \int_0^\infty u \phi_{tt}  -u \phi_{xx} \mathrm d t \mathrm d x \\
\overset{\text{Fubini}}{\Rightarrow}=& \int_\mathbb{R} \int_0^\infty u \phi_{tt}   \mathrm d t \mathrm d x - \int_0^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} u \phi_{xx} \mathrm d x \mathrm d t \\
\overset{\text{Int. by parts}}{\Rightarrow} = &\int_\mathbb{R} u(t)\phi_t(t) \Big \vert_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty u_t \phi_{t} \mathrm d t \mathrm d x  - \int_0^\infty u(x)\phi_x(x) \Big \vert_\mathbb{R} - \int_\mathbb{R} u_x \phi_{x} \mathrm d x \mathrm d t\end{align}$$
Typically test functions are chosen such that they have compact support.
Here this could be something like $\phi \in H_c^2(\mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty ) )$ which implies $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \phi(x,t) = 0, \lim_{t \to \infty} \phi(x, t)= 0$. Same holds for $\phi_x, \phi_t$.
Invoking this gives
$$ \begin{align}&\int_\mathbb{R} -u(x, 0) \phi_t(x, 0) - \int_0^\infty u_t \phi_{t} \mathrm d t \mathrm d x + \int_0^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} u_x \phi_{x} \mathrm d x \mathrm d t \\
\overset{\text{Int. by parts}}{\Rightarrow} =& \int_\mathbb{R} -g(x) \phi_t(x, 0) - u_t \phi \big \vert_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty u_{tt} \phi \mathrm d t \mathrm d x + \int_0^\infty u_x(x) \phi(x) \big \vert_\mathbb{R} - \int_\mathbb{R} u_{xx} \phi \mathrm d x \mathrm d t \end{align}
$$
Again, using the compact support of $\phi$ gives
$$ \begin{align} &\int_\mathbb{R} -g(x) \phi_t(x, 0) + u_t(x, 0) \phi(x, 0) \mathrm d x + \int_\mathbb{R} \int_0^\infty u_{tt} \phi \mathrm d t \mathrm dx -  \int_0^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} u_{xx} \phi \mathrm d x \mathrm d t \\
\overset{\text{Fubini}}{\Rightarrow}=&  \int_\mathbb{R} h(x) \phi(x, 0) - g(x) \phi_t(x, 0) \mathrm d x + \int_\mathbb{R} \int_0^\infty (u_{tt} - u_ {xx}) \phi \mathrm d t \mathrm d x\end{align}$$
which is the desired outcome for $u$ satisfying the wave equation.

Basically you can do all the steps in reverse order (if starting from $\int_\mathbb{R} \int_0^\infty \phi (u_{xx} - u_{tt} ) \mathrm d t \mathrm d x$) to get the same result.